# Как ограничить выполнения скрипта пределами блока?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код:

```
$('.js-radio').click(function(){

        var active = 'form__radio--active';

        $(this).addClass(active);

        $('.js-radio').parents('.js-radio--block').find('.js-radio').not(this).removeClass(active);

    });
```

Как ограничить его работу пределами `'.js-radio--block'` ?

Если такой блок один на странице, то проблем нет. Если несколько, то работает не корректно.
Необходим принцип работы `<input type="radio">`

Заранее спасибо!

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oxVQVN

Comment: html код добавьте в вопрос

Comment: похоже, что так `$(this).parents`. но пока это догадки

Comment: похоже `$(this).parent('.js-radio--block')` зачем все родители? или даже `closest('.js-radio--block')`

Comment: ой, да parent,  если даже не closest

Comment: @Jean-Claude `.closest('.js-radio--block')`?

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев да, но кода же я не вижу, поэтому догадки.

Comment: кода никто не видел, но три благородных дона ведут умную беседу :)))

Comment: @splash58 :))) Сам себе в голове задачу построил, сам решил, а что там у ТСа, уже не так важно)) Логически то задача простая

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев зато иногда такой простор для фантазии бывает. можно ведь и более сложное что-то порешать :) оторваться от рутины :))

Comment: добавить блокам id="уникальный идентификатор", и отобрать по нему. Чем то эти блоки между собой должны отличаться.

Comment: @MolbOrg зачем отличаться? есть пойнтер - this

Comment: @splash58 по причине существования самого вопроса, скорее всего существуют и другие решения, но предоставленной информации не достаточно, зависит от решаемой задачи и того что там есть. Больше похоже на проблему агоритма, чем техническую проблему. Но костыль спешит на помощь.

Comment: @Jean-Claude

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oxVQVN

Comment: @splash58 http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oxVQVN

Comment: @ВасилийБарбышев http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oxVQVN

Comment: @MolbOrg http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oxVQVN

Comment: Эх, раз, да еще раз!

Comment: ну да - `$(this).closest('.js-radio--block')`

Comment: @Jarvis Добавте это в вопрос, это улучшит его, чтобы потом не пришлось в коментариях вычитывать(кхм не в этом случае,но ...)

Comment: @MolbOrg сделал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решается так http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yOwZaN
Но теоретически вы должны понимать, что разным группам радиобаттонов надо давать различающиеся имена, не знаю как вы там их дальше обрабатывать будете, но учтите в дальнейшем.

```
$(function() {
    $('.js-radio').click(function() {

        var active = 'form__radio--active';

        $(this).addClass(active);
        $(this).closest('.js-radio--block').find('.js-radio').not(this).removeClass(active);

    });
});
```